# Why computing Preferential Attachment is costly?

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, numpy, graph

I have an undirected graph with 1034 vertices and 53498 edges. I'm computing the preferential attachment index for the vertices. The Preferential Attachment similarity between two vertices is defined as the multiplication of the degree of the first vertex times the degree of the second vertex. I noticed that my computations are very slow. It took 2.7 minutes to compute that for the mentioned graph. I'm not sure if it's my algorithm that is slow or something else is wrong. I would be very thankful if someone could have a little look into my code.

**Edit: I just realized that S is a 1034_by_1034 matrix. Looking at the nested for-loops it seems that it's a O(n^2) algorithm! I guess that is why it's slow. Don't you agree?**

```
def pa(graph):
    """
        Calculates Preferential Attachment index.

        Returns S the similarity matrix.
    """
    A = gts.adjacency(graph)
    S = np.zeros(A.shape)
    for i in xrange(S.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(S.shape[0]):
            i_degree = graph.vertex(i).out_degree()
            j_degree = graph.vertex(j).out_degree()
            factor = i_degree * j_degree
            S[i,j] = factor
    return S
```

Comment: I don't know python. Maybe you can save all out_degree(x) in a array. And then do the multiplication.

Comment: I think it depends on how the `out_degree()` function is implemented. If it's `O(1)`, I'm sure it will finish quick enough.

Comment: in general, for-loops in python suck for numerical stuff. If you can push down those for-loops down to the numpy level, (or use numba/cython), you can expect massive speedups. In numpy, most stuff can be done without for-loops, by using the axis argument on some methods, or just clever playing with indices. If you show that graph_vertex(i).out_degree() method, we can probably speed it up a lot

Comment: @justhalf The similarity matrix S is 1034_by_1034 matrix. So there are roughly a million elements in it. Maybe it's too much?

Comment: @LiuAmeng oh damit. It seems that finding the similarity matrix S is an O(N^2) operation.

Comment: It's indeed `O(N^2)` operation. But 1 million element is still small for computer, and it should finish under one second, considering that it's only multiplication that is required on your code.
Definitely the `out_degree()` part is taking the long time. You can try to change the `i_degree` and `j_degree` part with a constant to see the effect.

Comment: And I contend that it's a logical fallacy to say that: "Since this algorithm is `O(N^2)`, it is slow", because it depends on the input size. In this case, an input size of just thousands is still within one second running time for an `O(N^2)` algorithm. In your case, I believe it is slow in other part. Have you run the function only with the following statement? `A = gts.adjacency(graph)`

Comment: The graph is somewhat sparse, so you could perhaps change data structures to an adjacency list and loop through the list of edges rather than doubling looping through the vertices for O(E). Any edge not in the adjacency list would have a PA of zero. Otherwise, just building the matrix is O(N^2) ignoring what you actually do with it. You could also eliminate redundant calculations by grouping vertices by degree, but that may not actually be very helpful unless there are a sufficient number of common degrees.

Comment: Can't agree more with @justhalf

Comment: something O(N^2) stays O(N^2), no matter what you do, but if for each item, your calculation takes 1sec, or 1nanosec, i know what i would choose. And that is independend of the complexity. I am quite sure that we can get it to run much faster if you give us that method everyone is asking for (so i guess this is just saying "I disagree" with what you put in bold)

Comment: @justhalf indeed, I changed them to constant withouth out_degree() in it finished in less than a second!

Comment: @AlexTwain Can you post that method, so we can speed the whole up?

Comment: @usethedeathstar you mean out_degree()? It just returns the degree of a vertex. Actually I'm using this API graph-tool.skewed.de and the method is from there, unfortunately.

Comment: @AlexTwain Posted a solution which should speed up a lot, by abusing the symmetry of the problem. Can you compare the speed?

Comment: @AlexTwain Does my answer do what you need? Or do you want more speedups? If not, can you accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

With all i know about it, these are the speedups i can suggest:

zeroth speedup: the i_degree is not depending on j, so move it up one level

```
def pa(graph):
    A = gts.adjacency(graph)
    S = np.zeros(A.shape)
    for i in xrange(S.shape[0]):
        i_degree = graph.vertex(i).out_degree() # easy to see that this can be put here instead, since it does not depend on j 
        for j in xrange(S.shape[0]):
            j_degree = graph.vertex(j).out_degree()
            factor = i_degree * j_degree
            S[i,j] = factor
    return S
```

first speedup: calling out_degree() only N times, instead of 2N^2.

```
def pa2(graph):
    A = gts.adjacency(graph)
    i_degree = numpy.zeros(A.shape[0])
    for i in xrange(A.shape[0]):
        i_degree[i] = graph.vertex(i).out_degree()
    S = np.zeros(A.shape)
    for i in xrange(S.shape[0]):
        for j in xrange(S.shape[0]):
            S[i,j] = i_degree[i]*i_degree[j]
    return S
```

Second speedup: numpy instead of python for-loop

```
def pa3(graph):
    A = gts.adjacency(graph)
    i_degree = numpy.zeros(A.shape[0])
    for i in xrange(A.shape[0]):
        i_degree[i] = graph.vertex(i).out_degree()
    S = i_degree[:,None]*i_degree[None,:]
    return S
```

This abuses the symmetry of your problem.

Note: The `[None,:]` does the same as using `[numpy.newaxis,:]`. If you wanted to keep your code, you could also use an `@memoize` decorator on that `out_degree()` method, but it is better to use that only on stuff that is recursive, and this is not one of those cases.

Comment: +1 I believe this will be faster. (I didn't know you can do cross product like that in Numpy)

Comment: @justhalf i put in some more explanation on the speedups. The fastest speedup will be calling N times the out_degree() instead of N^2 times. Pushing the multiplication down to numpy level should speed up a little as well, but to know which speedup is biggest depends on the implementation of the out_degree method. The N^2 multiplication is just done in numpy (read:C), so has less overhead than in normal python. The N^2 times calling the out_degree() has been improved to N times.